# Where's my *insert Pokémon here* gone?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I just caught a 634CP Venonat, [and there was much rejoicing](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/cc/ccdb9c1bdc8c745ae389fd40950de56c0da8fd353a66724250f3e5b8e6ac9207.jpg).

This was recorded in my journal for future generations to view and marvel at:

[image: Marvel at my skill and handsomeness. MARVEL IT!]

I immediately hit Evolve on it, because it was fragging strong and I had enough candies.

It then proceeded to vanish into stray electrons. It's not in my Pokémon collection, it's not turned into a Venomoth, it's not re-integrated itself Dr. Manhattan style after restarting the app multiple times. I am 100% positive I didn't send it to the Professor to be ground into [Torgo's Executive Powder](https://theinfosphere.org/Torgo's_Executive_Powder).

Has anyone hit this particular bug before? Should we just chalk this up to a weird edge case and curse the gods?

Comment: ***This*** is how you write a question.

Comment: @KazWolfe I love your custom reject reason.

Comment: In all seriousness thiugh, while I don't have any reference for this (hence why I'm leaving this as a comment), I believe it may be an unfortunate blip in the communication between the client and server. There may still be hope - sometimes when data is sent one way, the process to send it back is skipped, and so it needs to be refreshed to send the data back again (just going off my experience with this sort of thing). Pray to the gods that they merely got sidetracked by taunting some poor unfortunate with a "Nearby" Growlithe, and forgot to send you your *[insert Pokemon here]* back.

Comment: :) Much better! What have people got against fun?

Comment: @JamesENL StackExchange hates fun for some reason. Unless said fun includes Unicorns. Just so you're aware, as the OP of this question, your rejects/accepts of edits are binding and immediate, so you don't have to wait for others to review. That and you can also rollback if you dislike an edit made by others. (But don't get into rollback wars please. Sort those out in Meta)

Comment: I feel guilty doing that, like I'm cheating doing that.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's your question and you get the final say in how it looks. As long as you're not rolling it back to be *worse*, nobody really cares. If it gets out of hand and becomes an edit war, we can always take it to Meta to settle it once and for all.

Comment: @KazWolfe As the question stands it could use a readability edit which would result in less fun sentences and more ***to the point***....

Answer (score 1):

This happens a lot to some people. So if you want that Venomoth back you might want to email Niantic and ask for your Venomoth back. Show them evidence that you had the Venonat, because one guy lost his Pidgeot and asked for it back and got an Articuno so people are going to exploit that and fake that they lost a pokemon in order to do that, so of course Niantic is going to be suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely got into an area of poor reception, or you left a wifi network and the game couldn't reset itself in time to register the venonat as a successful catch, and it disappeared. Try and stay in an area of good reception and don't leave a wifi network without restarting the game. 
(This has happened to me as well, but with a 20 cp pidgey xD)

Answer (score -1):

I've had this happen with a couple super rare Pokemon before ( it made me sooo mad) except I didn't evolve it was just right after they were caught. Try refreshing, closing and opening again. A lot of glitches have been happening lately because it is a fairly new game and servers are exploding with players.

Comment: That is literally the first thing I tried, as it says in the question.